# Template is missing users/create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the ruby on rails tutorial and I'm on Lesson 8 signup failure. I am getting a Template is Missing error when submitting information.

```
Missing template users/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/lexi87/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
```

I have double check the files that he has open line for line. Nothing is different.

**Users_controllers.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    # Handle a successful save.
  else
  @title = "Sign up"
  render = 'new'
  end
end
end
```

**New.html.erb**

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages'%>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %><br/>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br/>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Error_messages.html.erb**

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this user from being saved:
            </h2>
            <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
            <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <% end %>
```

**Users_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

describe "GET 'show'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    response.should be_success
  end

it "should find the right user" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  assigns(:user).should == @user
end

it "should have the right title" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => @user.name)

end

it "should have the user's name" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should have_selector('h1', :content => @user.name)
end

it "should have a profile image" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should have_selector('h1>img', :class => "gravatar")
end

it "should have the right URL" do
   get :show, :id => @user
   response.should have_selector('td>a' :content => user_path(@user), :href => user_path(@user))
end

end
  describe "GET 'new'" do



    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :new
      response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign up")
  end

 end

 describe "POST 'create'" do

   describe "failure" do

 before(:each)do
 @attr = { :name => "", :email => "", :password => "", :password_confirmation => "" }
 end

 it "should have the right title" do
 post :create, :user => @attr
 response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign up")
 end

 it "should render the 'new' page"
 post :create, :user => @attr
 response.should render_template('new')
 end

 it "should not create a user" do
  lambda do
    post :create, :user => @attr
  end.should_not change(User, :count)

end
end

end
end
```

Comment: I think its not able to find template when successfull creation happens. What you have in if condition of create method?? Is it has correct template path??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the advice.

The actual problem was I had a "=" sign after render. It was showing in their file but when I fast forward the video I notice it was not there.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to :action => :index
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Rails is expecting there to be a file called create.html.erb which renders when you successfully create a user.

If you don't want to have a create.html.erb file, you'll have to either render a different action or redirect. This would need to go in the spot where you have "# Handle a successful save."